# How to avoid a changePage immediately after ajax post with javascript

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jquery-mobile

Help!

I am using jquery mobile to submit a JSON string to my rails app via an ajax post. The string contains some data that I send via the following ajax call in a JS file:

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://" + MyURL + ".json",
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify(this.form),
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
success: onSaveSuccess,
error: onFailure,
complete: onComplete
});
```

This code works, but as soon as I press the button to submit the form, it changes the page to my home page (NOT EVEN THE PREVIOUS PAGE). I want to set this post up so that it doesn't change pages until I tell it to (in either the success or complete functions). I don't want the user to be thrown around different pages after submitting the post. Instead, I want to show my upload spinner until it is done, and then I will redirect them to a specific page.

Does anyone know how to do this?

My login screen uses a (nearly) identical ajax script, and it does exactly what I want. I am assuming that is because there is no page to go "back" to. I don't understand this behavior, so if anyone does, your advice would be appreciated.

Comment: did you add a `preventDefault()` to prevent the default submit action of the form?

Comment: You can redirect to any page upon submitting the firm using `$.mobile.changePage`.

Comment: Can you show us the complete code?

Comment: @leonhart I have a preventDefault() when the button is clicked.

Comment: @leonhart upon further review, I was using the preventDefault on the wrong click event. I have two events. One triggers the other, which then initiates the ajax post. Stupid mistake. Thanks guys.